# Is Flutter using logical pixels all the time?

Tags: flutter

Documentation is sometimes specific whether control uses logical or device pixels. In case of `Text` [the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/fontSize.html) clearly states

> The size of glyphs (in logical pixels) to use when painting the text

However other widgets, say `SizedBox` have much more [enigmatic descriptions](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/width.html)

> If non-null, requires the child to have exactly this width

I have tested `SizedBox` by running primitive app in a web browser, altering `MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio` through zoom function. I've compared it to what is displayed in Android emulator. It does not seem to use logical pixels (at least in a direct way). Does anyone know the answer to the question to save me from digging into source code/documentation?